# The differences between: deliver, ship, and transmit

Tags: differences, vocabulary

Are these definitions correct?

> **Delivered**: The package has arrived at your place.
>   **Shipped**: The package was just sent.

Which word can be used to describe that the package is on its way?  Can I use the word *transmit*?  Or is *transmit* only used for signals and diseases?

One other related question: What's the difference between *package* and *shipment* in an internet business?  Is a *shipment* bigger than a *package*?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89658/pack-package-packaging-parcel

Comment: they're totally the different questions

Comment: Samuel: I took the liberty to fix up your question. If English isn't your first language, then some mistakes might be inevitable. However, you should be able to follow some basic punctatuation and capitalization rules when posting here. As for my earlier comment, I said it was _related_, not a _duplicate_. I realize they are not the same, but the question I pointed to is not entirely unrelated to what you asked about (i.e., the difference between a _shipment_ and a _package_), in that those words (esp. _package_) can sometimes be used to describe either the contents or the container.

Comment: @J.R:I apologize my sensitive response. I'm just afraid that my question would be closed. BTW, Thank you for your suggestions. Finally I know the new word "inevitable" from you. I like it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ship* means to send something. *Deliver* means to hand over something to the proper recipient.

For example, if Amazon *shipped* your stuff to your address, it would be *delivered* to you at your address.

If an item is on its way, you can use the term *in transit*, which means it has left the warehouse and is on its way to your address.

Comment: FYI, "the item is *in transit*" is the usual expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two lines are correct:

- Delivery should mean the recipient has been given the package
- Ship should mean the package has left the warehouse

Transmit is not appropriate for a package, but is for diseases and signals etc.

A shipment could be a package or a consignment of packages.

Comment: :Tannks for you help.So which word can be used to describe that the package is on it's way

Comment: You can indicate that with past tense: _The package has shipped_ means that it's on its way.